# handling multiple button actions in one action in C#

Tags: c#, button

I have 70 buttons whose names are like button1, button2, button3 and so on.
My aim is that whenever button1 is clicked, it will say "1", button2 will say as "2" and so on for the others.

The code for button1 to speak is:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    synthesizer.Speak("1");
}
```

For button2

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    synthesizer.Speak("2");
}
```

and so on for other 68 buttons.

Now it is difficult to implement the 70 button's actions. These button actions follow a pattern - so can anyone suggest a more efficient way I can implement these button handlers to save me writing out 70 different actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use same handler for all buttons. Sender of event will be the button which raised event. You can get it's name and extract text to say:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    string text = button.Name.Substring("button".Length);
    synthesizer.Speak(text);
}
```

Comment: I used ...foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>()) // or do it in the VS properties
            {
                button.Click += button_Click;
            } .....then called button_click method.By this it is kinda slow to release a button action. @lazyberezovsky

Comment: @DarkenShooter you mean attaching handler to all events is slow?

Comment: @DarkenShooter just tested with 100 buttons - it takes about 0.2 ms to attach event handler to all buttons. Looks like you have problems elsewhere. You can use Stopwatch to measure event attaching timeout

Comment: I have tested with the action of speechSynthesizer.Is it for this?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
button1.Tag = "1";
button2.Tag = "2"; 
...

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    synthesizer.Speak(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a single handler for all of the buttons.

Cast the `sender` parameter to get the `Button` instance that was clicked, and figure out what to do based on its `Name`, `Text`, or `Tag`.

Depending on your UI, you might want to generate all of those buttons in a loop, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe them to a single eventhandler.

thus:

```
button1.Click += buttonClicked;
button2.Click += buttonClicked;
// and so on
```

and the code for the buttonClicked;

```
private void buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//This will get the Type first, the name and then the last character on the Name
        synthesizer.Speak(sender.GetType().Name.Substring(sender.GetType().Name.Length - 1, 1));
    }
```

this promotes code reuse for you :)